# Firestore check if document already exist using try await

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Trying to check if doc already exist before saving it but I wanted to use `try`, `await` here is my example:

```
try {
    const payload = await db.collection('cities').doc('LA').get()
    if (!payload.exists) {
      try {
        const payload = await db.collection('cities').doc('LA').set(data)
        if (payload.exists()) {
          response.send(payload);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        response.send(error);
      }
    } else {
      response.send({error: "document exists!"});
    }
  } catch (error) {
    response.send(error);
  }
```

Just wanted to check if it's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try/catch is not functionally any different than then()/catch().  It's just a different syntax that simplifies dealing with promises.

I don't know what your definition of "best way" is, but if it works OK for you with a minimal amount of code, I'm sure it's OK.